# resize image without div being resized

Tags: html, css

I looked over thousands of questions all of them they want to fit picture in a parent div. I can fit picture in a parent div but when I resize the picture to smaller size the div gets smaller as well. I tried **max-width: 80%** but the div gets smaller also. I don't want the div box to resize because there are other buttons and lists in the page that move with it. And I cant use background-image trick as well. The only solution is to set for example **height: 150px** for box div but that also gives me problem for smaller screen sizes. Can anybody be any help? This question probably will be flagged duplicated but I gave up on searching.

```css
    .box { 
      width: 100%; 
      float: left;
    }
    .picture {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      max-width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box">
      <img class="picture" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: advise that you write media queries for smaller screener sizes

Comment: try with transform: scale(0.5) ;)

Comment: @Synoon Best answer possible :) I wish this was an answer I could verify :)

Comment: @RachelGallen media query not fixing the current problem, But I'm taking the advice for same box smaller screen sizes :) Thanks

Comment: @EvikGhazarian added as a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm honestly not completly sure what your asking about but solving the size of a picture inside a div with paddings and margins is not what we want to do. there you have to use `media-queries` to get responsiveness.

> try transform: scale(0.5)

scale let you resize your content dependent on how big your content was initially.

```css
.box { 
      width: 100%; 
      float: left;
    }
    .picture {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      max-width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      transform: scale(0.5);
    }
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <img class="picture" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your box element should have a height too. Also, set a position relative to it and a position absolute to the image. The child element should always be placed inside the parent with an absolute position. This way you can individually set sizes and positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport height for div (vh) as per your need.

```
.box { 
      width: 100%;
      height:100vh;
      float: left;
      border:2px green solid;
      margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .picture {
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      max-width: 80%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/fvezsnjb/10/

Edit-
You can use **object-fit** for adjusting the image inside div also. Set value of object-fit to **scale-down** or **contain** as per your need.

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/fvezsnjb/27

Comment: height: 100vh is pushing down everything else underneath down to out of screen. my box should be arround 200px maximum.

Comment: Please see : https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/fvezsnjb/27/. Please use **object-fit: scale-down;** in picture class

Comment: I get the same result with or without object-fit: scale-down

Comment: I have commented out the required CSS rule set in this example. Now the image is also resizing. Please specify the height of div you want 200px or 300px. Let me know if it works : https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/fvezsnjb/43/

Answer (score 0):

Try making the `div` absolute and the image relative to it. I have added a border to the div to see if the image is moving by itself as a test:

```
.box {
   position: absolute;
   border: 5px dotted blue; // For testing (remove after done testing)
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}

.picture {
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px 50px 50px 100px; // Moves the image within the div tag
    outline: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Expected Output:

[image]

**EDIT:** Adjust the `padding` and `width` values according to your code expectations.

Please See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2jrts0y/8/)

Comment: When I apply the position: absolute to the box it disarranges everything else on the page. texts and buttons under the box goes behind the box.